# How to perform this query in oracle sql?

Tags: oracle

Lets say I have the TABLE shown below. Could you please help me find the persons that have the Attribute1 **but not** the Attribute3?

[image: TABLE]

Thanks,

Christina

Comment: You are not using both mysql and oracle. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: I have tried the below statement but it does not return the desired results: select personId from TABLE t1, TABLE t2 where t1.personId=t2.personId and t1.AttributeId='Attribute1' and t2.AttributeId<>'Attribute3' group by personId.

Comment: @christinasantz please, just edit your question and post the relevant code along with it.

Comment: @christinasantz - I guess you're referring to my response. Please explain **how** the results it gives differ from the results you desire. If you want us to help you really must provide sufficient details. All we know about your situation is what you post​ here. We are not mind-readers.

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways of solving this. Here's one

```
Select person_id from your_table
Where attribute_id = 'Attribute1'
Minus
Select person_id from your_table
Where attribute_id = 'Attribute3'
/
```

Comment: Should we even be answering a low quality question like this? The consensus is *no*.